# tikz - pgfmathresult prints nothing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I am trying to use a foreach statement to print the powers of 2. I start by defining n as 2 then I print n and multiply it by 2 10 times. The code does compile without errors but the only number I see in the output is the page number. Am I misusing pgfmathresult?

Code below ----

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{2}
\foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
    \pgfmathparse{\n}\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{2*\n}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put it in a `\node {\pgfmathparse{\n}\pgfmathresult};` otherwise the `tikzpicture` environment won't show any bare text (on purpose). The body of a loop is also scoped, so `2*\n` will not be available at the next iterations, use `\foreach[remember=\n]`. (You could just evaluate `\n^\i`, by the way.)

Comment: You can use \foreach outside a tikzpicture. In which case it would print the result.

Comment: Bare text inside a tikzpicture isn't rendered. The font is set to `\nullfont` explicitly to avoid random bits of text appearing where it shouldn't. A tikzpicture environment is designed to put stuff at specific positions, but bare text doesn't come with positional information so tikz ignores it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,siunitx,calc}
\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 0}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{2*\i}
            \node at (\i,1) () {\num{\i}};
            \node at (\i,0) () {\num{\n}};
        }       
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two cases without use of any libraries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
with \verb+\pgfmathparse+

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,...,10} 
    \node at (\i,0) {\pgfmathparse{int(2*\i)}\pgfmathresult};
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
with \verb+evaluate+ defined in \verb+\foreach+ macro

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \n using int(2*\i)] in {1,...,10}
    \node[red] at (\i,0) {\n};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The comments to your question already give some useful hints:

Don't use a `tikzpicture` environment if you don't need it. Text outside of a node won't be printed inside `tikzpicture` environments, but you can use the `\pgfmath` macros outside of this environment as well.

Since the `\foreach` loop creates a scope, the new value of `\n` will be lost after each loop. You can avoid this by adding the option `remember=\n` to the `\foreach` macro. You may want to use the `int()` function which will strip off the decimals. Finally, just typing `\n` is sufficient to print its value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

foo 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{2}%
\foreach [remember=\n] \i in {1,...,10} {%
    \n%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{int(2*\n)}
}%
bar

\end{document}
```

[image]